# How do you control the length of generated nvarchar columns when using EF4 Code First?

Tags: entity-framework-4, data-annotations, ef-code-first

I am using EF4 Code First (CTP5) to generate my database and I am using DataAnnotations to try to control the generated DB schema.  If I use the [Required] attribute, then the column is correctly generated as NOT NULL, but when I try to use the [StringLength(50)] attribute, all my columns end up getting created as NVarChar(max).

Here is a snippet of code for one of my clases (simplified) so you can see my problem:

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    // This property is generated as NVarChar(max) NOT NULL
    // I prefer it be NVarChar(50) NOT NULL
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a first name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="First name is too long")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

If the [StringLength] attribute isn't working, is there another way to control the generated nvarchar column lengths?

Thanks,
Brent Stewart

Comment: You must be doing something wrong because these data annotations work for me. Do you map anything in `OnModelCreating`? Did you recreate the database after adding data annotations?

Comment: Thanks for verifying that it is working properly.  After learning that, I decided to check my tools and discovered that LINQPad doesn't report these columns correctly (CE4 database).  I checked the column type using WebMatrix and sure enough it was being created correctly.  Thanks again.

Comment: You can either delete or more better answer your own question because it can be useful for others and answer should not be in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue I was experiencing was caused by a bug in LINQPad where it was not accuratly reporting the column types of my SQL Server CE 4 database.  The [StringLength] Attribute worked exctly as it should.